# Events and delegates, public or private?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, private, public

I have a problem with a variable. `X1` is a variable with events and methods for defect `X1` is private and 
if I change this variable's visibility to public I can only call it this way:

```
X1.OnCapture += delegate { Myresult = X1.Result; }
```

but I don't know if the variable should be private. If it should, I'd need to add a delegate to a private variable like this:

```
public enum EventsEnum
{
    OnCapture, OnChange, OnConfiguration, OnDelete, OnError, OnIdentify, OnRegister, OnScan, OnScannerStatus, OnVerify
}

public string dfes(System.EventHandler Delegado, EventsEnum Events)
{
    string Result = "";
    switch (Events)
    {
        case EventsEnum.OnCapture:
            X1.OnCapture += (Delegado + delegate
            {
                Result = X1.result;
            });
            break;
        case EventsEnum.OnChange:
            X1.OnChange += (Delegado + delegate
            {
                Result = X1.result;
            });
            break;
        case EventsEnum.OnIdentify:
            X1.OnIdentify += (Delegado + delegate
            {
                Result = X1.result;
            });
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return Result;
}
```

What is the right way to do this? Do I need to make the variable private? Is making a variable public a bad practice? Thank you. I'd really appreciate any help to do this as correctly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:
`public`
The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.

`private`
The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.

So. If you want to get access to some field, property, event from another class then you must use `public`.
More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx